# How to justify this step in complex geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

An example in my engineering mathematics textbook asks to find the radius of convergence of the following series and analyze what happens *on* this radius of convergence.
$$P(z)=1-\frac{z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{4}-\frac{z^3}{8}+...$$
I obtained the radius of convergence as 2; the series converges for $|z|<2$ which is inline with the book. But as we let $z=2e^{i\theta}$ as a complex number on the circle of radius 2, then,
$$P(2e^{i\theta})=1-e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}-e^{i3\theta}+... \tag{1}$$
Now this looks like an infinite geometric series with starting value equal to 1 and $r=-e^{i\theta}$, so $|r|=1$, meaning the series diverges. But my book simply states that this infinite series evaluates to
$$\frac{1}{1+e^{i\theta}}$$
So the series also converges on the circle of radius 2 as long as $\theta\neq\pi$. But as far as I know, we need the common ratio to be strictly in between -1 and 1; it cannot equal to 1 or -1 exactly. So how is convergence of $(1)$ still justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the series does not converge for $|z| = 2$. Indeed, if we write
$$P_n(z) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n \left(-\frac{z}{2}\right)^n,$$
then $|P_{n+1}(z)-P_n(z)| = \left(\frac{|z|}{2}\right)^{n+1}$, which does not tend to $0$ if $|z| = 2$. Thus the series does not converge in that case. The only way to make sense of this is to either consider $\lim\limits_{\substack{z \to 2e^{i\theta} \\ |z| < 2}} P(z)$ or to redefine what summation means such as [Cesaro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation). In both instances you would indeed get $\frac{1}{1+e^{i\theta}}$ as a result.